# How to eliminate lines between points

Tags: matlab, plot

This is my code to create a `surf` plot. The problem is, that I'm using MATLAB for the first time and I can't get rid of the lines, connecting the points `23:45` and `00:00` on the next day. The created plot:

[image: This shows the created plot]

```
a=nan(1,208)'
Date=[column1;a]
Time=[column2;a]
Usage=[column3*3.5*77.826;a];
Datere=reshape(Date,188,[])
Usagere=reshape(Usage,188,[])
Timere=reshape(Time,188,[])
surf(Datere,Timere,Usagere)
```

How can I remove those lines?

Comment: Why are you adding a column of zeros to all your data ? The two first input of `surf`represent your grid, and this grid need to be continuous in order to work properly

Comment: Instead of adding `zeros(1,208)`, try adding `nan(1,208)`, since `0` is a plottable number, whereas `NaN` will not show up in the plot, presumably removing the lines.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i still got the issues with the connecting lines.